# How to tell from within a pod that the container is running on a preemptible node?

Tags: google-kubernetes-engine

I using GKE to run a cluster with a mixture of preemptible nodes and non-preemptible nodes.

I am using `requiredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution` to restrict target deployments to two node-pools: preemptible and non-preemptible, and I am using `preferredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution` to prefer `preemptible` pools.

I want to encourage steady pod migration to preemptible nodes. I think I can do this by detecting this pods are running in non-preemptible node and regularly shutting them down. The preference setting will first attempt to schedule new pods in the preemptible node pool.

How to tell from within a pod that the container is running on a preemptible node?

Comment: You might be able to achieve this in k8s but it will take a little extra work. You can use [Env variables](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/inject-data-application/environment-variable-expose-pod-information/) to deliver pod and node information down to the container. You can pull node specs using these variables. For example, you can use k8s labels on each node pool which will be recognized by the node spec, or you can define labels on the preemptable node pool and using downward API of K8s get that information.

Comment: If that doesn't solve the issue, you can let me know more clarifications about your use case to let us help you better.